# Convert (User,Role,user_role) SQL Raw Query to Eloquent In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Respected sir,I have to fetch user role name from user_role pivot table.

I successfully done by this using Sql Raw Query.but i have to use Eloquent.
Please convert below raw sql code into Eloquent,Please help me 
sir i am new in laravel.

```
$role = DB::table('users')
    ->join('user_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_roles.user_id')
    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'user_roles.role_id')
    ->select('roles.name')->where('users.id', '=',$user->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: sorry sir/ma'am ,  I want to use eloquent function to fetch roles name .

Example belongsToMany , etc

Answer (score 1):

you could try Laravel Eloquent's `manyToMany` relationship. It's the same exact setup as you have here with a pivot table.

Add this method to your `User` model

```
function roles {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

In your controller you could use

```
$roles = User::with('roles:name')->where('id', $user->id)->get();
```

Do try this method, you dont have to change anything to you db just adjust your model and controller.

For more info [here's the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)